# AWS 3-tier architecture issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, cloud

Guys I am trying to implement a 3-tier architecture to host a web app on aws.
The requirements given to me are as follows.

The app will leverage a 3-tier architecture:

1. A Web Server that will be running on S3
2. An application tier running on ECS Cluster on Fargate or a fleet of EC2s with ASG (your choice)
3. A data tier running on RDS Aurora PostgreSQL latest supported version

I understand perfectly what to do on the 2nd and 3rd instructions for the App and Database tier.
What I don't get is the **“web server running on s3”** . Is it possible to have a web server on S3?

What I know is, I can have a web server running on EC2.

Please, I need some explanation here.

Comment: You can deploy a static website to S3, meaning the interaction with your middle tier needs to happen via JavaScript https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/host-static-website/

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no, S3 is a static file host, which means you have these HTML, CSS, and JS files where all you want to do is to send these files to the browser, then absolutely, yes. S3 can be used as a file serving service, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteHosting.html

However, when you have the case where your website is doing some real-time HTML generation, something like SSR (Server Side Rendering), S3 won't cut it. S3 does not process the code in any way and only directly sends the files as-is to the frontend. In which case, you need a more traditional server on EC2/ECS/EKS.

Comment: So it definitely means it is possible to run a web server on S3

Comment: if by webserver you define it as just sending files to your browser, no serverless processing. yes, yes you can use it as a web server.